# Altering MMenu contents after initiation

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I have an `MMenu` object which I created a custom CSS class for that will show circular red alerts. Everything works fine, as long as the alert HTML is present in the `li` element *before* the `MMenu` object is initiated. However, this is problematic as I need to check for alerts in real-time with ajax and if new alerts are present, I need to update the `MMenu` HTML *after* it's been loaded.

Is there a way to alter the HTML/contents of an `MMenu` list *after* it has been intitiated? I read in the documentation that you cannot destroy an `MMenu` instance, so unfortunately I cannot destroy and recreate it with the new HTML.

Here is a fiddle and my sample CSS showing how I do this. As you can see in the fiddle, the code should load the same red bubble with the number "2" next to the "Petitions" link, like the "Messages" alert, but simply altering the original HTML does not allow you to change what is displayed on the screen.

https://jsfiddle.net/2r9tsmyn/9/

**JS**

```
var API = $("#dashboard-menu").mmenu({
  extensions: ["fullscreen", "pageshadow", "pagedim-black", "iconbar", "theme-dark", "border-full", "effect-menu-slide", "effect-listitems-slide"],
  offCanvas: {
    position: "left"
  },
  navbar: {
    title: "Dashboard"
  }
}).data("mmenu");
$(".dashboard-link").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  API.open();
});

$("#dashboard-menu .mm-title").addClass('ani').css('cursor', 'pointer').click(function() {
  API.close();
});


$('li.mm-peition a').append('<div class="mm-alert">2</div>');
```

**CSS**

```
.dashboard-menu ul li a {
  position: relative !important;
  display: block !important;
}

.mm-alert {
  display: inline-block !important;
  float: right !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
  width: 24px;
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I took a look at your fiddle and it looks at though there was a spelling mistake in your jQuery selector, you had

`$('li.mm-peition a').append('<div class="mm-alert">2</div>');`

> note the incorrect spelling of petition. When I ran your fiddle it
>   started working.

That said, if you're looking to make dynamic changes to your menu take a look at the documentation for dynamic content: http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/tutorials/dynamic-content.html

While there isn't a destroy method on the menu you can make changes with jQuery and then call:

`API.initPanels( $("#my-list") );` which can be your base list panel if you wish.

One gotcha I came across was that when you add a panel you need to find the panel within the list item you're adding to and append to that like it says in the documentation.

`#my-list was an UL, now is a panel
 $("#my-list").find( ".mm-listview" ).append( li );`

Calling initalise after this should work fine.